# Python: Calling a function from a file that has current file imported

Tags: python, function, import, call, program-entry-point

I tried searching around but didn't seem to find an answer to my problem, so I'm sorry if I missed something and it actually has been answered before.

So basically I have main.py and another file called check.py (both in same directory)

In my main.py I have:

```
from check import checkfunction
```

I have a small function inside main.py that I MUST call inside check.py, but I can't seem to get this import working on my check.py:

```
from main import mainfunction
```

How can I get the mainfunction to work inside check.py?

Thanks!

Comment: "Can't get it to work" means? What is the exact error or problem?

Comment: When I run main.py, I get error "ImportError: cannot import name checkfunction". Only happens when I have both imported in each other.

Comment: Import the whole module and call the functions with `main.mainfunction` and `check.checkfunction` respectively.

Comment: Inside main.py I changed the import to "import check" and inside check.py I respectively changed it to "import main". Now when I try to use "check.checkfunction" inside main.py, I get the following error: ImportError: cannot import name checkfunction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options:

- Move the common function to a module imported by both other modules.
- Merge both modules into one.
- Pass the function from main to the code that needs to call it.
- Monkey patch the function into the check module after importing it.
- Refactor the whole thing so that you don't have circular dependencies.

If you actually explained why you have this design, someone could possibly propose a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a design with a circular dependency which is usually a bad thing as your two python modules are tightly coupled.

Consider refactoring your code. But if you must stick with your design please see the following SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python) for more info on how circular imports work in Python and the various gotchas to look out for.