# Python: How to call a function in an imported file, from the main one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found the same question, but I can't comment an answer there.
[Python: Calling a function from a file that has current file imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332069/python-calling-a-function-from-a-file-that-has-current-file-imported)

I have one.py:

```
import two

def one_bis()
    print('something')

def one():
   two.two() 

one()
```

... and two.py:

```
def two():
    one_bis()
```

Ulrich Eckhardt throw some posibilities and there're two that I'm interested in (in bold):

> - Move the common function to a module imported by both other modules.
> - Merge both modules into one.
> - **Pass the function from main to the code that needs to call it.**
> - **Monkey patch the function into the check module after importing it.**
> - Refactor the whole thing so that you don't have circular dependencies.

How should I do those solution?

Comment: Refactor your code so you don't have to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your "how do I do it the complicated way?" question but one more alternative to do this.

```
# one.py
import two

def one_bis():
    print('something')

def one():
   two.two()

one()
```

.

```
# two.py
def two():
    from one import one_bis
    one_bis()
```

If you really want to patch module `two` then add the following code to module `one` before you call `one()` (which calls `two.two()`).

```
two.two = one_bis
```

But I recommend refactoring your application.

Comment: Isn't this a "non suggested" circular dependency?

Comment: If you're talking about my first solution: Yes it is (and I wouldn't recommend it), but it is a _working_ circular dependency.

Answer (score 1):

well I don't know if this helps, but I did a bit of tinkering and found that for me, the best method is to pass it in as an arguement, I was also looking for something similar, so here it is

```
# one.py
import two

def one_bis():
    print('something')

def one():
   a=one_bis
   two.two(a)

one()
```

then

```
#two.py
def two(n=None):
    if n!=None:
        return n()
```